# How to perform open graph in dynamic routing in react js as given below

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, facebook-opengraph

For other static routes open graph is working fine but when dynamic routes are used it's not

Example code
`<Route path="/blogs/:slug" element={<SanityBlog />} />`

And this is SanityBlog code

[Click to check Actual Full Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxDzT.jpg)

```
   export const SanityBlog () => { 

      const data = useContext (BlogContext);
      const { slug } = useParams(); console.log(slug);
      const navigate = useNavigate(); 
      let slugTitle = slug.split("-").join(" ");
      return data && C
       <>
       <Helmet>
         <title>{data.metatitle}</title>
         <meta name="description" content={data.metadescription} />
         <meta property="og:title" content={data.metatitle}/>
         <meta property="og:description" content= 
         {data.metadescription} />
         <meta property="og:image" content= 
         {data.mainImage.asset.url}/>
        </Helmet>
        <Header /> 
        <BlogBody/>
        <SEOSection/>
        <Footer/>
        </>
     );
```

When working on static routes open graph is working fine but when used dynamic routes its not like you see above

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.